# how to compare dates of two separate column only if another selected column fits a condition

Tags: r

just wondering if anyone can help me with this frustrating problem- im not sure how to go about it as it involves a combination of problems. I'm pretty new to coding so there may be some unclear points in this question- please let me know if something doesn't make sense!

an example of my data

```
#reproducible data (hopefully)

dat <-structure(list(id = 1:5, 
                     opstart = structure(c(1514970000, 1514904000, 1514916900, 1514883900, 1514979600), 
                                         class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     crdate_1 = structure(c(1514818380, 1514965080,1514752680, 1514760180, 1514919480), 
                                          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                      crdate_2 = structure(c(1515058680, 1515058740,1514817780, 1514965080, 1515064560), 
                                          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     crdate_3 = structure(c(1515564000, 1515137700,  1514876100, NA, 1516101000), 
                                          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                      aki_1 = c("aki", NA, NA, NA, "aki"),
                      aki_2 = c("aki", NA, "aki", NA, "aki"), 
                     aki_3 = c("aki", "aki", "aki", NA, "aki")), 
                    row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
id             opstart            crdate_1            crdate_2            crdate_3 aki_1 aki_2 aki_3
1  1 2018-01-03 09:00:00 2018-01-01 14:53:00 2018-01-04 09:38:00 2018-01-10 06:00:00   aki   aki   aki
2  2 2018-01-02 14:40:00 2018-01-03 07:38:00 2018-01-04 09:39:00 2018-01-05 07:35:00  <NA>  <NA>   aki
3  3 2018-01-02 18:15:00 2017-12-31 20:38:00 2018-01-01 14:43:00 2018-01-02 06:55:00  <NA>   aki   aki
4  4 2018-01-02 09:05:00 2017-12-31 22:43:00 2018-01-03 07:38:00                <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5  5 2018-01-03 11:40:00 2018-01-02 18:58:00 2018-01-04 11:16:00 2018-01-16 11:10:00   aki   aki   aki
```

> 

what I am trying to do is to make a new column called aki_status using mutate which will detail whether "aki" was before the opdate or after the opdate. crdate_1 corresponds to aki_1, and crdate_2 corresponds to aki_2 etc.

the complication is that the aki_status should be based on the column which "aki" first appears. so for example, for the first row, aki comes up in aki_1, so crdate_1 would be used in the comparison against opdate, but in row three, aki comes up in aki_2 first, so crdate_2 should be used in the comparison against opdate.

the ideal output would be

```
aki_status(preop, postop, preop, NA, postop)
```

Comment: hi- thanks for letting me know- it should be fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that relies on first reshaping the original data into a longer format that is easier to work with. The table "spec" here defines which column ("date, "aki", or "obs") we want the columns in the source data to feed into.

```
library(tidyverse)
spec <- tribble(
  ~.name,    ~.value, ~obs,
  "crdate_1", "date", 1,
  "crdate_2", "date", 2,
  "crdate_3", "date", 3,
  "aki_1",    "aki",  1,
  "aki_2",    "aki",  2,
  "aki_3",    "aki",  3
)

dat_long <- pivot_longer_spec(dat, spec)
```

This table is easier to work with since it allows us to directly compare each crdate with its respective opstart date, while keeping track of which round it is.

```
#> dat_long
## A tibble: 15 x 5
#      id opstart               obs date                aki  
#   <int> <dttm>              <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>
# 1     1 2018-01-03 09:00:00     1 2018-01-01 14:53:00 aki  
# 2     1 2018-01-03 09:00:00     2 2018-01-04 09:38:00 aki  
# 3     1 2018-01-03 09:00:00     3 2018-01-10 06:00:00 aki  
# 4     2 2018-01-02 14:40:00     1 2018-01-03 07:38:00 NA   
# 5     2 2018-01-02 14:40:00     2 2018-01-04 09:39:00 NA   
# 6     2 2018-01-02 14:40:00     3 2018-01-05 07:35:00 aki  
# 7     3 2018-01-02 18:15:00     1 2017-12-31 20:38:00 NA   
# 8     3 2018-01-02 18:15:00     2 2018-01-01 14:43:00 aki  
# 9     3 2018-01-02 18:15:00     3 2018-01-02 06:55:00 aki  
#10     4 2018-01-02 09:05:00     1 2017-12-31 22:43:00 NA   
#11     4 2018-01-02 09:05:00     2 2018-01-03 07:38:00 NA   
#12     4 2018-01-02 09:05:00     3 NA                  NA   
#13     5 2018-01-03 11:40:00     1 2018-01-02 18:58:00 aki  
#14     5 2018-01-03 11:40:00     2 2018-01-04 11:16:00 aki  
#15     5 2018-01-03 11:40:00     3 2018-01-16 11:10:00 aki
```

Now we can look at the first "aki" within each "id", to get a summary stat "aki_status" for each "id".

```
results <- dat_long %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(aki == "aki") %>%
  slice_min(date) %>%  # or slice_min(obs) -- same result always?
  mutate(aki_status = if_else(date < opstart, "preop", "postop"))

dat %>% left_join(results, by = c("id", "opstart"))

  id             opstart            crdate_1            crdate_2            crdate_3 aki_1 aki_2 aki_3 obs                date  aki aki_status
1  1 2018-01-03 09:00:00 2018-01-01 14:53:00 2018-01-04 09:38:00 2018-01-10 06:00:00   aki   aki   aki   1 2018-01-01 14:53:00  aki      preop
2  2 2018-01-02 14:40:00 2018-01-03 07:38:00 2018-01-04 09:39:00 2018-01-05 07:35:00  <NA>  <NA>   aki   3 2018-01-05 07:35:00  aki     postop
3  3 2018-01-02 18:15:00 2017-12-31 20:38:00 2018-01-01 14:43:00 2018-01-02 06:55:00  <NA>   aki   aki   2 2018-01-01 14:43:00  aki      preop
4  4 2018-01-02 09:05:00 2017-12-31 22:43:00 2018-01-03 07:38:00                <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA                <NA> <NA>       <NA>
5  5 2018-01-03 11:40:00 2018-01-02 18:58:00 2018-01-04 11:16:00 2018-01-16 11:10:00   aki   aki   aki   1 2018-01-02 18:58:00  aki      preop
```